# A ListView binding ObservableCollection<T>, I need to refresh ListView but it cost long time

Tags: wpf, listview, binding, observablecollection

I have a ListView that binding an ObservableCollection object (named Categorys) in ViewModel, Now I need to clear Categroys and then fill it again by a result from socket. this progress may cost 10 sec, I want ListView still show datas in this 10 secs. How can I do? make a copy of Categorys?

Answer (score 0):

If you are replacing the entire collection, why not have the service getting the data from the socket create a new ObservableCollection on a background thread, then when it is complete, set your ViewModel.Categorys = newCollection.

Comment: when I use newCollection.Clear(), ListView still display nothing...;)

Comment: why are you clearing the new collection?  It would help if you posted some code into your original question to help understand what and how you are trying to accomplish your task.

Comment: thanks a lot, I found a way.  Only this line spend time. var result = Communication.SocketAPI.Instance.ListFile(string.Empty, FolderType.None, generateCommandID());           so I Clear Categorys after this completely.

Comment: Changes of ObservableCollection<T> will notify UI, so ViewModel.Categorys = newCollection and newCollection.Clear() still make UI display nothing.

Comment: I think this is the reason. Don't know is it correct or not.